# Store value of string between two characters

Tags: vba, excel

I'm searching for a way to store the value between two characters in a string. For example a string like: "I like apples (because I don't like pears).".

How would I be able to get "because I don't like pears" and store that in a variable?
Is there a way to get all text between the parentheses?

Thanks for taking the time to read this!

Comment: Will there always be text in parentheses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks you for your help!
For anyone who's having the same challenge I think I found the simplest sollution.

```
Sub gettextbetween()
Dim text As String

text = "I like apples (because I don't like pears)."
MsgBox Mid(text, InStr(1, text, "("), InStr(1, text, ")") - InStr(1, text, "(") + 1)

End Sub
```

The **InStr** returns the number at wich the value, in this case "(" is found. The **Mid** function can get the value of a string starting at a specific number for x amount of characters.

Again thank you all for your help!

Comment: FYI: You should probably still check for parentheses. I believe `InStr` returns a `0` when it fails; and `Mid` would error if you try to use a start position of `0`.

Comment: Your right! I didn't check that. I'll check if the parentheses are there using: `If Not InStr(1, text, "(") = 0 And Not InStr(1, text, "(") = 0 Then MsgBox Mid(text, InStr(1, text, "("), InStr(1, text, ")") - InStr(1, text, "(") + 1)`

Thanks @Mistella !

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
dim str as string
str = "I like apples (because I don't like pears)."
str = split(split(str, ")")(0), "(")(1)
debug.print str
```

The nested Split (`split(str, ")")(0)`) converts the string into a zero based array with two elements; e.g. `I like apples (because I don't like pears` and `.` and returns the first of these.

The wrapping Split (`split(xxx, "(")(1)`) converts the return into another zero-based array with two elements; e.g. `I like apples` and `because I don't like pears` and returns the second one.

Comment: Note: if this is used on a string without parentheses, the second split will give an error (out of bounds). However, that could be solved with an intermediate step of storing **all** the results of the second split into a variable. Then extract the last item from that array. (You could also do this in one line; however, that gets more complicated.)

Comment: Good point; expanding the nested splits into individual code lines and adding error control based on the ubound of the result(s) should guarantee success.

Comment: or a check `If str Like "*(*)*" Then`

Comment: Actually, I would probably just append a `(` to str in which case vbnullstring would be returned if no brackets were found; e.g. `str = Split(Split(str, ")")(0) & "(", "(")(1)`